# ¿Como actualizar una celda de un dataframe por el índice de la fila?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Tengo un dataframe y lo estoy iterando con un bucle `for` para consulta una data en un webservice:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print 'esto es i =', i
    nit = mydataset_df.iloc[i]['CO_tin_no']
    print 'valor de nit', nit
    url = 'http://www.rues.org.co/RM/ConsultaNIT_json'

    headers, payload = {
            'Content-Type':
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }, {'txtNIT': nit}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, timeout=4)
    if r.json().get('rows', False):
        res = r.json()['rows'][0]
        legal_name = res['razon_social'].title()
        print legal_name
        print '##############################################'
       #mydataset_df['legal_name'] = legal_name
    else:
        legal_name = 'no existe el numero %s' %nit
        print legal_name
        print '**********************************************'
       #mydataset_df['legal_name'] = legal_name
```

El bucle funciona y la respuesta en cada iteracion es :

```
esto es i = 0
valor de nit 19xxxx71
Pardo yyyy YYYY xxxxx
##############################################
esto es i = 1
valor de nit 86xxxxx85
Alberto yyyy XXXX yyyyy. Ltda 
##############################################
esto es i = 2
valor de nit 79xxxx29
no existe el numero 797xxxx29
**********************************************
```

En mi dataframe necesito crear una columna llamada "legal_name" y escribir el valor resultante en cada iteracion, por lo que deberia resultar:

```
nit      | legal_name
19xxxx71 | Pardo yyyy YYYY xxxxx
xxxxx85  | Alberto yyyy XXXX yyyyy. Ltda 
79xxxx29 | no existe el numero 797xxxx29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres usar el nombre de la columna para indicar dónde vas a actualizar, puedes usar [`at()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html), ej:

```
mydataset_df.at[i, 'legal_name'] = legal_name
```

O bien [`loc()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) que te permite eventualmente pasar una array de valores para actuar sobre múltiples filas a la vez, a diferencia de [`at()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) que solo aplicaría a una fila en particular, aunque este último, justamente por esta diferencia suele ser más rápido.

```
mydataset_df.loc[i, 'legal_name'] = legal_name
```